# Can not open shared folders on my Ubuntu PC by its name until I open one of them using IP

Tags: windows-10, networking, ubuntu, network-shares

There are few Win10 and 1 Ubuntu PCs in my local network. I can see only Win PCs and a router in my Network,  while Ubuntu PC is invisible. When I try to connect to the Ubuntu PC by its name I receive a message:

```
Network Error
Windows can not access \\LinuxPC
Check the spelling...
```

Ping returns

```
> ping LinuxPC                                                          
Ping request could not find host Linux PC. Please check the name and try again.
```

Only after I open my Ubuntu PC by its IP and open one of the shared folders it starts to open and pinged by its name.

Any advice on how to fix it?

P.S. my router id D-Link DIR-300 which acts as DHCP server and my Ubuntu PC is listed in its list:

```
Host Name   IP Address  MAC Address Expired Time
LinuxPC 192.168.0.104   00:0F:FE:F1:C6:A1   17 hr(s) 20 min(s)


C:\Users\Kosh>ipconfig /all
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : SMALL
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0F-FE-F1-C6-4A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9cd4:a904:b37:7524%15(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.102(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 25 июня 2020 г. 14:36:37
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 29 июня 2020 г. 13:31:18
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 100667390
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-25-A9-68-88-00-0F-FE-F1-C6-4A
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: Need to know router, and what your local DNS settings are - DNS is what ties the IP to the name.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I have included that in to my question

Comment: still no dns settings

Comment: @JohnnyVegas my router is my DNS server, I had included ipconfig /all output into my question

Comment: everything looks ok but router isn't resolving the dns properly. Set each computer you need to access to a reserved IP address on the router (so the IP address does not change) then add the names to the /etc/hosts file (system32/drivers/etc/hosts on windows) - This will let you use names instead of typing IP's.